# How can I grow  herbs in my kitchen?

Tags: indoors, herbs

I am attempting to grow some herbs in my kitchen and I was wondering how frequently I should water them? Also my kitchen isn't the warmest so I am attempting to keep them near the radiator, is there anything else I can also do, e.g. insulate them or something?

Thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different herbs will vary, but make sure they don't dry out, also that they are not soaking (which could lead to rot/etc). They will dry out more quickly near a radiator.

They also need light. is the radiator below a window? Is so the sill could be an excellent place - especially if it gets a lot of sun.

Comment: Thanks very much, they are not getting that much light at the moment but I just planted them, do they need the light straight away or just once they have sprouted?

Comment: Technically, probably not but I do yes. Seeds that are planted very shallow depths will benefit from the light as soon as they germinate. Also the natural warmth from sunlight might be beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

The radiator probably isn't helping unless it's below freezing. Your biggest problem is going to be lighting. Most herb need direct sunlight.

**DIRECT SUNLIGHT**!

Maybe your kitchen uses natural lighting but getting *direct* sunlight indoors is difficult.

This is what the experts have to say:

> Herbs need as much light as possible, preferably the natural variety
>   from the sun. Direct sunlight, at least four or five hours a day, is
>   the minimum herbs need. Even with that, and with plants positioned
>   close to a south, east or west facing window, I like to recommend
>   supplying supplemental artificial light from growlights.

If you don't have direct sunlight you should consider either a hydroponic lamp or simply rotating indoor/outdoor pots every few days.

As for watering:

> When watering, it is better to water more throughly and less often. A
>   good principle to follow is to water until water comes out of the
>   drainage holes in the bottom of the container.

And don't forget about soil:

> Inexperienced gardeners may think that if soil in the garden is good
>   enough to grow herbs or other plants, then the same soil must be good
>   enough for potted herbs. That’s wrong because of the water drainage
>   factor. Good garden soil drains well enough in the garden, but in a
>   container the walls of the container restrict the movement of water in
>   the soil column. Even in unglazed terra cotta containers it is
>   important to use a good potting mix that contains amendments such as
>   perlite or vermiculite or sharp builder’s sand to allow water to move
>   freely.

Quotes taken from this great resource: [Growing Herbs Indoors](http://www.richters.com/show.cgi?page=MagazineRack/Articles/indoors.html)